# 02 FORESTER VOLTAGE

Tags: subaru, forester, voltage, knock-sensor

Ran the codes on 02 Forester.  We came up with P0328  Knock Sensor.  I am  putting on new fuel filter and plug wires.  Does anyone know what voltage I should be pulling off of the knock sensor.  Right now it is pulling 1.0   Thanks

Comment: See this page...https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/p0328-obd-ii-trouble-code-knock-sensor-1-circuit-high-input-by-spencer-clayton

Answer (score 1):

Here's the diagnostic procedure for a P0328 code from the FSM for the 2002 Subaru Forester. I believe it covers everything. Replacing the knock sensor is trivial, and a new one costs about $75.

[image]

The knock sensor Is #5 in the diagram below, you have to remove the air cleaner box to access it. It is bolted to the engine block.

[image]
[image]

After the repair, clear the codes - otherwise you'll think it's still broken!

Comment: Always here to help. @PeteCon